# Subtable in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I have a little shop and I want to insert my order into the database. For Example:

Order Number: 1

Products:

- Apple, Price: 2$, Amount: 2, Total Price: 4$
- Banane, Price: 3$, Amount: 1, Total Price: 3$
- Orange: Price: 2$, Amount: 2, Total Price:  2$

Total Price: 9$

So I made now in my database a table with 3 rows (order number, products, total price)

But how can I list all my products in my row "products" in my database. Is there something like a subtable in mysql?

Comment: Order number, products, total price are (should be) columns, not rows. The rest of the questions sounds like you should do some research first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want store **products** and **orders** in database you must create **three** tables.

```
products
  id
  name
  price

orders
  id
  date


orders_products
  id_order
  id_product
  amount
```

It's very simple schema, but it's simple solution to start understand this

Example data

```
products
  |id | name   | price|
  |---|--------|------|
  | 1 | Apple  | 1000 |
  | 2 | Orange | 2000 |

orders
  | id | date                |
  |----|---------------------|
  | 1  | 2015-18-03 00:21:00 |

orders_products
  | id_order | id_product | amount|
  |----------|------------|-------|
  |    1     |     1      |   1   |
  |    1     |     2      |   2   |
```

Show all products

```
Select * from products
```

Show order #1

```
Select * from orders where id = 1
```

Show all products from order 1

```
Select * from orders_products op 
join products p on p.id = op.id_product 
where op.id_order = 1
```

How you see, third table store relation, and with join you may retrieve information about products in order

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. I try to understand, but how can I relate multiple products to one order?

Comment: Third table in my example will store all products from order, i am add information to example

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, thank you, I also found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380034/how-to-store-complex-product-order-data-in-mysql